# trying hard to take the last element from a list (Haskell)

Tags: list, exception, haskell

Here is my code, however, i've got no idea how is it wrong, here is my codes:

```
ll :: [a] ->  a
ll lis = case lis of
  (_:xs) -> ll xs
  [] -> error"xx"
```

and there is no error message from terminal:
but when i run "ll [1, 2, 3]", i suppose to get "3", however, i get the result of "*** Exception: xx".

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks XD

Comment: What's wrong with the last function? http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/last_f.html

Comment: think of an expression that would catch the last element before the recursion gets to the empty list (add that before `(_:xs) -> ll xs`.

Comment: @groovy, get it, problem solved, thx man XD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're never returning the last element of the list. The first case clause drops the first element of a non-empty list then recursively calls `ll`. Eventually, you'll hit the empty list case and hence the error gets raised.

Comment: Thx for replying, but even i added  "[x] -> x" between (_:xs) and [], it still gives the same result

Comment: @libra That's because the `(_:xs)` pattern already matches `[x]`. Put that one first.

Answer (score 6):

I find it helpful to start with the base case of the recursion:

```
ll [x] = x
```

Then the recursion:

```
ll (_:xs) = ll xs
```

Of course giving a helpful error message is good style. It's often convenient to do this last, when no case matches:

```
ll _ = error "empty list"
```

And as a bonus the WTF!?! version:

```
import Data.List

ll = foldl' (flip const) (error "empty list")
```

You could call `flip const` the "Alzheimer's function", it simply forgets its first argument and returns the second, and as `foldl'` digs through the list from left to right, it will give you the last element.

Comment: This is clever! I hope I won't forget the Alzheimer's fun.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation using predefined functions:

```
ll = head . reverse
```